# AngularJs Checkbox that will toggle selected on all other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJs (Angular 1) and I need to use a checkbox to Select / Unselect all other checkboxes.

Right now I have this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">{{item.name}}
</li>
```

Then I have this in the controller:

```
ctrl.items = [
    {
        value: 0,
        name: 'Select All / Unselect all other checkboxes',
        selected: true
    },
    {
        value: 1,
        name: 'myCheckbox1',
        selected: true

    },
    {
        value: 2,
        name: 'myCheckbox2',
        selected: true

    },
    {
        value: 3,
        name: 'myCheckbox2',
        selected: true

    }

];
```

How can I make it so that the first checkbox basically just selects / unselects all other checkbboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('MyController', function(){
   var ctrl = this;
   
   ctrl.changed = function(item){            
      if(item.value == 0)
        for(var x of ctrl.items)
          x.selected = item.selected;
   }
   
   ctrl.items = [   
      {
          value: 0,
          name: 'Select All / Unselect all other checkboxes',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 1,
          name: 'myCheckbox1',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 2,
          name: 'myCheckbox2',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 3,
          name: 'myCheckbox2',
          selected: true
      }
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MyController as ctrl'>
  <li  ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change='ctrl.changed(item)'>{{item.name}}
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-onchange="selectAll()">{{item.name}}
</li>
```

then in the controller,(you can add conditions for toggling)-

```
selectAll(){
  angular.forEach(items,(item)=>{
   item.selected=true;
});
}
```

Comment: That will trigger the action on any checkbox that is selected, not just the first as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

simply watch you'r model for any changes

```
$scope.$watch('item.selected', function() { 
                if ($scope.item.selected == 0){
                    $scope.myCheckbox1.selected= false;
                    $scope.myCheckbox2.selected= false;
                    $scope.myCheckbox3.selected= false;
                } else {
                    $scope.myCheckbox1.selected= true;
                    $scope.myCheckbox2.selected= true;
                    $scope.myCheckbox3.selected= true;
                }

    }
```

Comment: This solution is awful.

Comment: It's awful for that reason and also because there is absolutely no need of any watchers in this case

Comment: yes you can use even ng-click here its a lot faster :| should i correct the answer or its done ?

Comment: Yeah first I would remove the watch and add an ng-change or ng-click, then I would use a cycle for setting the values instead of going through them one by one. Then I would manage better the condition for select, unselect everything. The code above doesn't work. Just add a snippet and test it to check

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="all(item)">{{item.name}}
</li>

all(firstItem){
    if(firstItem.value == 0)
        angular.forEach(ctrl, function(item, key){
            item.selected = firstItem.selected;
        })
}
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: The code  approach is totally correct but in this way you will call your all function to all the checkboxes. This is not what the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('MyController', function(){
   var ctrl = this;
   
   ctrl.changed = function(item){            
      ctrl.items.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.selected = ctrl.items[0].selected;
});
}
   
   ctrl.items = [   
      {
          value: 0,
          name: 'Select All / Unselect all other checkboxes',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 1,
          name: 'myCheckbox1',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 2,
          name: 'myCheckbox2',
          selected: true
      },
      {
          value: 3,
          name: 'myCheckbox2',
          selected: true
      }
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MyController as ctrl'>
  <li  ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
   <label ng-if="$index === 0" >
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="ctrl.changed(item)">{{item.name}}
 </label>
   <label ng-if="$index > 0" >
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">{{item.name}}
 </label>
  </li>
</div>
```

Why splitting up the elements? Because you need that ng-change code to be called just on the first element. If you want to bind (as most probably you may do) another ng-change on the rest of the elements, you can separate the functions and keep your code clearer and cleaner